# Should I pass multiple values in url or should I fetch the values from the database again?

Tags: php

I'm trying to create an image uploading website where all images are displayed on one page, one below the other. Now on this page, I display many of the image's properties such as the name of the person who has uploaded the image, the number of likes for the image, etc. and this I do for every image. I obtain these values from a database. Now when someone clicks on any image, I want the person to be directed to a page where only that image and its properties are displayed.

Now, to do this, should I pass all the properties of the image, that I have already obtained from the database, through the url? If yes, then is it safe? And if no, then should I just pass the id of the image through the url and then fetch the values all over again from the database? Won't this be inefficient?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Safety will come into picture only if you send sensitive and confidential information, such as user's password or any key along with the URL. Since your image details are not classified as confidential, I would say pass the image id along with the URL and fetch the image details from the database on the other page, it's not inefficient.

Comment: Oh okay Thanks!..and what if I store them in session variables?

Comment: Using session data would work, but... should someone be allowed to link to the details for a particular image?  If so, the image id would need to be contained in the URL....

Comment: You could. However, you have to change the session variable values every time user clicks on an image.

Comment: Oh okay..so I shall fetch all the details for the image again..Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing the identifier by URL is certainly much better. Why?

**Best practice:**

It's not a question of safety but rather of best practice. Passing the identifier is more understandable by any developer. It can be helpful if you work in a team or if you have to rework your code later.

**Special chars:**

When you pass parameters by URL (with the GET method) you have to pay attention to special characters. Spaces for example must be encoded.

**Performance:**

Unless you have millions of visits each day, one more database request will not kill performance. Moreover you can do little optimizations:

Do your first request only on `id` and image `url` and the second on all information for one image.

*Example:*

```
SELECT id, url FROM imageTable
SELECT * FROM imageTable i WHERE i.id = requestedId
```

So, the full table doesn't have to be loaded at the beginning, which is handy if not all users will go looking for the images' details.